# How to put jQuery "fancybox" plugin values in array\variable and use it later using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have multiple fancyboxes in my code and want to minimize options inside the fancybox to use whole block of options like a variable or an array to make code look nice and call options by one string of code. How can i do it with javascript?

```
$(".present_window").fancybox({


            "wrapCSS": "call",
            "padding": 0,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false,
                    opacity: 0.1,
                    css: {
                        'background': 'rgba(90, 92, 94, 0.8)'
                    }
                }
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be that's what are   you looking for https://jsfiddle.net/hrw1c2b4/

```
var optionCoffee = {
    wrapCSS: "call",
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false,
            opacity: 0.1,
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(90, 92, 94, 0.8)'
            }
        }
    }
};

$(".present_window").fancybox(optionCoffee);
```

Comment: Thank you, Vixed, it was so simple!